# JQueryMobile dialog shows twice because of a postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, timer, dialog, postback

I have an asp.net page with a timer embedded in an UpdatePanel (UpdateMode="Conditional", ChildrenAsTriggers="false"). The timer is responsible for updating some components of that page every few seconds.

There are also some HyperLink controls on the page and they open a JQueryMobile dialog when clicked (data-rel="dialog"). The problem is that the timer i mentioned causes postback every few seconds. So when a dialog is opened and then closed, the first such postback after then causes the dialog to open once again.

Using the rel="external" as another attribute of the HyperLinks I mentioned solves the problem, but this is no solution for me. This causes full redirection to the dialog page instead of showing it using AJAX (as if on top of current page).

My idea was to stop the timer when any hyperlink is clicked. This solves the problem, but I have no idea how to start the timer again when the dialog closes. Is it possible to detect when a JQueryMobile dialog is closed? I know, this sounds stupid, but I can't come up with a better idea. Will you help me, please?

So basically, I don't want the JQueryMobile dialog page to show up for the second time after a timer tick. Could you please advise me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile with asp.net Web Forms and an `UpdatePannel`? This just sounds like a horrible combination.

jQuery Mobile and Web Forms fundamentally don't work well together. The specific issue that Web Forms requires a single `<form />` element that wraps all controls (and most content). jQuery Mobile attempts to build up the DOM with "virtual" pages via ajax loading. This breaks the PostBack model by submitting the entire form instead of the individual form found within each page template. Now throw `UpdatePanels` in there...

Your only hope is go exclusively with Single page templates and to disable all ajax loading `data-ajax="false"` on both links and forms. And just say no to `UpdatePanels`.

asp.net MVC would give you much greater control over these issues.

Comment: The problem is that there was an ASP.NET WebForms application and I was supposed to make it look like a mobile app :-). So I did it using jQuery Mobile, often struggling with issues like this one... I have never developed any ASP.NET MVC app before, but I it seems I will have to try. I think it is possible to mix MVC with WebForms, so I'll try to do it this way and to move completely to MVC with time (there are only a few pages to convert). I hope it won't be very difficult.

Comment: You can also stay with Web Forms if you disable all of the ajax loading within jqm but that is likely to impact performance on mobile devices esp over 3G/4G.

Comment: But it looks much worse then :(. I disabled data-ajax on every form, but still want to use it for showing dialogs. When they are open with AJAX, the transition looks much better than without it. Let me go further - I tested that app on BlackBerry and when I closed a dialog that was open with AJAX, then the previous page was properly displayed. However, when I opened a dialog with rel="external", then closing it led me to a page full of random text (looked like some base64-encoded content). This is the main reason why I would like to stick to AJAX for dialogs...

Comment: Ya. You are likely in uncharted territory trying to combine these technologies.

Comment: I know this may sound stupid, but I saw it :). It seems that closing a dialog that was open with rel="external" does not work properly on BlackBerry. I'll check this once again tomorrow to be 100% sure and not to spread some nonsensical statements :).

Comment: Thanks for your support. Nevertheless I have to find a solution to this issue. Lets go back to my simple idea of stopping the timer when a hyperlink is clicked. I did it with a few lines of a javascript code. The timer stops and everything is fine. But when the dialog is closed, I have to start it again. That's really important. If only I was able to detect the moment of closing the dialog box, I think it would be enough for me.

Comment: When I bind to any of the following events of the dialog window (pagehide/unload), I'm unable to differentiate between events called by the source page and by the dialog :(. It seems that those two pages coexist somehow and and it is impossible to determine which of them causes these events at a given moment :(. Sorry if I tell nonsense, but I'm new to web development. These are just the results of my tests...

Comment: I've just noticed that when a dialog is open, the code of that window is injected into the source code of the original page. I would give myself minus 100 points for this idea, but I have no better one: a javascript timer that will be checking periodically for the existence of the injected code. As long as it is there, the ASP.NET timer will not be run. When the dialog is closed, the injected code disappears, so then the ASP timer can be run again... OMG, kill me for that. I'll let you know if that works. I hope I will never have to write such code again.