# jQuery Mobile and ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: jquery-mobile, webforms

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.1 and .NET 3.5 WebForms.  I've got a few dropdowns that I populate with choices in the Page_Load after checking !Page.IsPostBack.  When using JQM, the UpdatePanel with these dropdowns comes back with all of the dropdowns empty.  I feel like this is something with ViewState because it's all of the controls that were previously filled by the code.  The dropdowns that are filled out in the ascx don't have the same problem.

The only thing in my mobileinit is:

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile, asp.net web forms and update panels simply don't work with one another:

[JQueryMobile dialog shows twice because of a postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402300/)

You may also be having issues related to the select menu not refreshing when changes occur within the update pannel. Consider manually refreshing that:

```
$("#mySelectMenu").selectmenu("refresh");
```

Comment: The style is fine because I'm calling trigger("refresh") but asp.net is sending the markup back with an empty select.  20% of the time it works fine.

Comment: You're right, the update panels just don't work.  I dumped all the asp.net controls and just did HTML/jQuery with an ASMX web service.

Comment: My mobile web sites (of which there are 2 at this point) consist of almost entirely static MVC Razor pages with close to zero server side code. I am mostly using MVC for its controllers as endpoints to my ajax calls.